# Unsuccessful Forge Symbolic Package Installation

Tags: package, octave

I am trying to install the symbolic package from Octave Forge. I've tried downloading the `.tar.gz` file and running `pkg install symbolic-2.7.1.tar.gz` but it did not work and I tried using pkg install -forge symbolic and it also failed. I already installed Python and SymPy with conda and I dont really know what the issue is about.

As stated in the release notes from the package, it should not be necessary to download anything, however the warning I get suggests that I need the `.tar.gz` file in the directory.

As a last resource, I downloaded the `.tar.gz` file once more and placed in the directory, but it vanished right after i run install -forge again. I dont know if that was a mistake. Any clarifications are very much appreciated.

```
pkg install -forge symbolic
warning: file C:\Users\X\Desktop\SisDin 1\4o teste\symbolic-2.7.1.tar.gz does not exist
```

Comment: it seems to have worked. In the release note, however, says "pkg install -forge symbolic". Thank you for the help, Andy.

Comment: https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/releases here is the link

Comment: v2.7.1 is the version